# Mariadb / MySQL JAVA Prepared Statement Syntax Error

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

```
               // Attempt to get 1 transaction
                String sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO '" + this.crawlPageTableName
                        + "' (url, status) VALUES (?, 'added')";

                PreparedStatement prest = connect.prepareStatement(sqlQuery);
                prest.setString(1, this.url);
                
                System.out.println("Querying with: " + sqlQuery);

                // Result set get the result of the SQL query
                this.resultSet = prest.executeQuery();
```

I am really not getting what I am doing wrong here to get this error.

The output of printline is

```
Querying with: INSERT INTO 'crawlPage' (url, status) VALUES (?, 'added')


java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: (conn=1877278) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''crawlPage' (url, status) VALUES ('
```

I am really lost here as the same query from the printline works directly on the MariaDB server through phpMyAdmin.

Comment: If table names need to be escaped, they should be enclosed in backticks `\``, not single quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you shouldn't have any single quotes wrapping the table name:

```
String sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO " + this.crawlPageTableName
                        + " (url, status) VALUES (?, 'added')";
```